# Checking all function arguments length at once in R

Tags: r, function

As a sanity check, I want when any arguments in function `seda` below is a vector of length larger than 1, the function stops.

**Question:** Instead of individually listing all function arguments (here `x`, `y`, `z`), is there a way to use `match.call` or `formals` etc. such that ALL function arguments could be checked at once?

I tried the below with no success:

```
seda <- function(x, y, z){

  is.v <- function(...) lengths(list(...)) > 1
  if(is.v(match.call())) stop("Error") # instead of `is.v(x, y, z)`

  x + y + z
}

seda(2, 2, 3)
seda(c(2, 3), 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly appreciate the input of my expert colleagues. Using your valuable comments, I guess what I want is the following:

```
seda <- function(x, y, z){

if(lengths(list(get(names(match.call()[-1])))) > 1) stop("Error")

 x + y + z
}

seda(c(2, 3), 2, 3) 
seda(2, 2, 3)
```

Also we could perhaps use `formals` as well:

```
   seda <- function(x, y, z){

    if(lengths(list(get(names(formals(seda))))) > 1) stop("Error")
     x + y + z
     }

   seda(c(2, 3), 2, 3)
   seda(2, 2, 3)
```

Or `formalArgs` like this:

```
    seda <- function(x, y, z){

     if(lengths(list(get(formalArgs(seda)))) > 1) stop("Error")
       x + y + z
        }

       seda(c(2, 3), 2, 3)
       seda(2, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

`match.call()` will capture the arguments to the function, which can then be tested for length. We use `sapply` to return a vector with the length of each function argument, and the `any` function to test whether any of the arguments have a length greater than 1.

```
seda <- function(x, y, z){

  if(any(sapply(match.call()[-1], length) > 1)) stop("All arguments must be length 1")

  x + y + z
}

seda(2, 2, 3)
```

> ```
> [1] 7
> ```

```
seda(c(2, 3), 2, 3)
```

> ```
> Error in seda(c(2, 3), 2, 3) : All arguments must be length 1
> ```

Thanks to @erocoar for pointing out that `match.call` can be used instead of `sys.call` and that `as.list` is unnecessary.

Comment: Why not use `pars = match.call()` ?

Comment: Yes, right, just need to convert that to a list. For some reason I thought of `sys.call()` then realized I needed to convert that to a list, but didn't think to just do that with `match.call()`. Thanks. I'll update my answer. (Looking at the help, I see that `match.call` actually uses `sys.call`.)

Comment: Yeah, thinking about it I think you can use both `sys.call()` and `match.call()` without the `as.list()`

Comment: I am baffled as to why a negative parameter is reported as length 2, e.g. `seda(1, 1, -1)`. Hoping someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak what you have a bit to get it to work:

```r
seda <- function(...){
    stopifnot(lengths(list(...)) == 1)

    sum(...)
}

seda(1, 1, 1)
#> [1] 3

seda(1, 1, 1:2)
#> Error: lengths(list(...)) == 1 are not all TRUE
```

...or with named parameters,

```r
seda_named <- function(x, y, z){
    stopifnot(lengths(list(x, y, z)) == 1)

    x + y + z
}

seda_named(1, 1, 1)
#> [1] 3

seda_named(1, 1, 1:2)
#> Error: lengths(list(x, y, z)) == 1 are not all TRUE
```

To use `stop` instead of `stopifnot` so as to control the error message, wrap the condition in `all`.

Answer (score 0):

If they are tested all at once then the error message won't say which argument was the problem. The following tests them in a loop and does indicate which was the offending argument in the error message.

```
seda <- function(x, y, z) {
  argnames <- names(match.call()[-1])
  for(nm in argnames) if (length(get(nm)) != 1) stop(nm, " does not have length 1")
  x + y + z
}

# test - note that the error message names z
seda(10, 20, 1:2)
## Error in seda(10, 20, 1:2) : z does not have length 1
```

Of course if you really had 3 arguments it would be a lot simpler just to write it out. This also gives argument specific error messages:

```
seda <- function(x, y = 1, z) {
  stopifnot(length(x) == 1, length(y) == 1, length(z) == 1)      
  x + y + z
}

seda(10, 20, 1:2)
## Error: length(z) == 1 is not TRUE
```